# Matlab Coder, Cell Array Not Fully Defined

Tags: matlab, cell-array, matlab-coder

I have built the following function:

```
function [obs,dw,rot] = myfun(T,obs,dw,dt,rot)

if rot == 0

        v = (0:dt:T(1)-dw);
   obs{1} = v./T(1);
       dw = (dt+v(end)-T(1));

for i = 2:numel(obs)

        v = (dw:dt:T(i)); 
   obs{i} = v./T(i)+(rot+(i-1));
       dw = (dt+v(end)-T(i));


end
else

for i = 1:numel(T)

        v = (dw:dt:T(i)); 
   obs{i} = v./T(i)+(rot+i);
       dw = (dt+v(end)-T(i));


 end

end

rot = rot + numel(T);

end

end
```

For instance,

`dw=0; rot=0; dt=1; T=1+2*rand(10,1); obs=cell(length(T),1);`

And apply

`[obs,dw,rot] = myfun(T,obs,dw,dt,rot);`

When I try to use **Matlab Coder** to speed up myfun,
It shows the following error:

MATLAB cell array 'obs' is not fully defined.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is `foo` in your example?

Comment: you have your function and your variable declaration in the same .m file ? Where m is defined ?

Comment: No. m could be defined anytime before. I'm just posting part of the code to emphasize  that m could have variable size.

No, I have the function in a different .m file and I just call it as `mycell = myfun(vec,mycell)`

Comment: You could post an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to avoid guessing.

Comment: why are you using `Coder` to speed up your function? wouldn't `profile viewer` to the trick? i assume your error lies in the fact that the cell array is an empty array when handed to the function. In my version `define Input types` of coder assumes that the content of each cell would be a 0x0 double

Comment: Because in general, mex files are faster. Also, I need to use large vectors (divided by blocks), so I am trying to reduce CPU time.

Comment: So there is no way to send an empty array when using Matlab coder?

Comment: Try moving the line  obs=cell(length(T),1); inside your function myfun and avoid passing it as input.

Comment: Coder doesn't allow to have variable size cells inside a function...